# In "has only examples of ...", is it reasonable to view "only" as an adjective?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage

This post is not a duplicate of ["her dog doesn't even want" vs. "even her dog doesn't want"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239482/109190), since that post does not explain why "only" could not be used as an adjective in my second example.

---

I made up a sentence in another post ([Did I put focusing adverbs in the correct position?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239382/109190))

> Cambridge Dictionary **only** has examples about "complete list".

where I used **only** as adjective, is it still also idiomatic and grammatical if I use **only** as adjective?

> Cambridge Dictionary has **only** examples about "complete list".

Cambridge Dictionary defines **only** as adjective

> used to show that there is a single one or very few of something, or that **there are no others**

I guess "there are no others" fits with my 2nd example, only "complete list" no "full list".

I used "only" again ([What type of adverbs "also" is?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239631/109190))

> I found lots of people using "You can also", more than 1k hits **only** on ELL. And myself use "also" a lot as well.

and still don't have a clear understanding about its usage.

Comment: This is ***exactly*** the same syntactic issue you just asked about with [“her dog doesn't even want” vs. “even her dog doesn't want”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/239482/), where the relevant grammatical principle is that ***only*** is "Prefixed to the particular word, phrase, or clause in which the **paucity / uniqueness** of the case is expressed". But with your specific example here it makes little sense to consider "only **having**" something as being some kind of "lesser" activity (as opposed to ***using*** it, perhaps?), so we don't really care about the position of **only**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["her dog doesn't even want" vs. "even her dog doesn't want"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/239482/her-dog-doesnt-even-want-vs-even-her-dog-doesnt-want)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you. I thought "only" in "has only examples" is an adjective rather than an adverb.

Comment: No, it's an adverb in both your examples. It's an adjective in, for example, "my only reservation".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you. Would you please explain a bit, why could **only** not be used as adjective in my 2nd example?

Comment: @WXJ96163 Focusing adverbs like "only" don't modify nouns or nominals (as opposed to noun phrases). "Examples about complete list" is a noun phrase, so "only" must be an adverb, not an adjective.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you. Is "nominal" a grammar term in modern English? I know it's a canonical term in statistics though, it is not the case here.

Comment: A nominal is the bit between the noun phrase and the noun. For example, in "the **guy who fainted**", the bit in bold is the nominal, i.e. the noun phrase less the determiner "the".

Comment: I'm not sure that ***adverb / adjective*** categorisation is relevant here. The point is the "default target" for words like ***only*** and ***even*** is *whatever immediately follows* (be it a noun, verb, or whatever). That was the answer for the previous question, and it's still the answer for this one. It's the general principle / default parsing that counts, not the specific examples.

Comment: The focus doesn't have to immediately follows the modifier. In, for example, "I only saw granny at weekends", the focus is the PP "at weekends", which is not adjacent, but the sentence is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: It's just about possible to use ***only*** adjectivally with a plural subject, as in *Jack and Jill are **only children*** - with the slightly "unexpected" meaning that neither of them have any siblings, not the "natural" reading (that they're *merely* children, as opposed to being adults). But I can't ascribe any real-world meaning to the collocation ***only examples*** if parsed as an "adjective + plural noun" construction.

Comment: @BillJ I would post a new discussion on nominal vs. noun phrase if necessary. Would you please give a recognized reference for this rule "what can modify nouns or nominals"?

Comment: @BillJ "Focusing adverbs like "only" don't modify nouns or nominals" seems not relevant here, I guess we're discussing if "only" could be used as adjective in my 2nd example, right?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica "I'm not sure that adverb / adjective categorisation is relevant here", I guess it is relevant, since the rules in your answer to my another post (dog ... even) is for adverb, not for adjective, right?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I guess "there are no others" fits with my 2nd example, only "complete list" no "full list". So, I guess "only" could be used as adjective there, at lease per this rule. Please correct me if I misunderstand any, I really want to figure this out.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica in "It's just about possible to use only adjectivally with a plural subject", does the "plural subject" refer to "Jack and Jill" in the subsequent example?

Comment: @WXJ96163 Look, forget adjectival "only". In both your examples it's an adverb. OK?

Comment: @BillJ Thank you. Would you please explain why "only" could not be used as an adjective in my second example. In other words, would you please help make modification on that example to demonstrate how to use "only" as an adjective?

Comment: @WXJ96163 I've already explained the reason. Why are you obsessed with "only" being an adjective?

Comment: @BillJ I really don't get a clear understanding why "only" could not be used as an adjective in my second example though, I'll accept it's an adverb in both my examples. And then, do they mean the same? which one is more appropriate?

Comment: @WXJ96163: Bad choice of words on my part. In my "plural adjectival" examples, **Jack and Jill** is indeed the (plural) ***subject of the verb ARE***. But I was talking about the word-pair ***only children***, within which I'm saying "only" adjectivally modifies the plural noun "children" - perhaps I should have said "children" is the ***target*** of the adjectival modifier "only" rather than the subject. I take it you do understand that ***an only child*** is a noun phrase referring to a child who has no siblings.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thanks for your patience, I guess I've figured out the "plural adjectival" part. Back to the beginning, does "don't really care about the position of only" mean both my examples are idiomatic, right?

Comment: Absolutely! Native speakers are often very careless about exactly where they place words like "only". I suspect this is *particularly* true in the context of verbs like "to have, to be" because they often occur in contexts where the *intended* meaning is obvious. So although "We only sell cubic zirconia jewelry" should logically mean ***selling is all we do with that type of jewelry** (...we don't **repair** it, for example)*, in practice that's such an unlikely meaning you'd need heavy stress on the word ***sell*** to convey that, or it'd be understood as *...we don't sell anything else*.

Comment: ...where it's just a bit too "contrived" to imagine using ***have*** instead of ***sell*** in that example, but hopefully you can see what I'm getting at (in a sufficiently weird context, *I only **have** cigarettes* could imply *I merely **possess** cigarettes; I don't actually **use, sell,*** or do anything else with them*).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica  Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. Would you please move/copy your comments to answer, I'll accept it.