# "why could sth not be used as ...", is it an idiomatic expression?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

In my another post (["only has" vs. "has only", when to use which?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239565/109190)) I said

> This post is not a duplicate of ..., since that post does not explain **why could "only" not be used** as adjective in my 2nd example.

"why could sth not be used as ...", is it an idiomatic expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Explain why could 'only' not be used" is not grammatically correct and it's not idiomatic.

Here's what the *Macmillan Dictionary* says about *why*:

> Why can be used in the following ways:
>
> as a **question adverb** (introducing a direct or indirect question): Why didn’t you call me?I know why he’s worried. (followed by an infinitive without “to”): We can start now, so why wait?
>
> as a **relative adverb** (referring back to a noun and introducing a relative clause): She’s tired and that’s the reason why she’s so bad-tempered. (introducing a clause that is the subject, object, or complement of another clause): Everyone in Dublin is so friendly, and that is why I love the city.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/why_1

When *why* is used as a relative adverb - as it is in your sentence - it must be followed by a noun or a pronoun:

*Tell me why **he** did it*
*Explain why **dogs** chase cats*

This is true even when the sentence has an auxiliary verb:

*Tell me why he **had** done it*
*Explain why dogs **were** chasing cats*

This is different from sentences that use *why* as a question adverb:

*Why **had he** done it?*
*Why **were dogs** chasing cats?*

In your sentence, you seem to be reversing the standard word order, **as if this sentence were a question**, but it's not.  You're using *why* as a relative adverb, so the standard word order must be used:

*That post does not explain why **"only" could** not be used as an adjective in my second example.*

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. You are such a great teacher! When that sentence is in the correct order, is it idiomatic?

Comment: @WXJ96163, yep, the corrected sentence, the one in italics at the end of my answer, is idiomatic.