# What type of adverbs "also" is?

Tags: adverbs

I found lots of people using "You can also", [more than 1k hits only on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22You%20can%20also%22). And myself [use "also" a lot](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A109190%20also) as well.

However, after I went through [2](https://www.myenglishteacher.eu/blog/types-of-adverb/) [posts](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv202.shtml) and [one grammar dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-types), I still don't know what type it is.

per another [post](https://brainly.in/question/9099716)

> There are at least **eight** different kinds of adverbs and these are adverbs of manner, adverbs of frequency, adverbs of time and place, adverbs of relative time, adverbs of degree, adverbs of quantity, adverbs that focus, adverbs that function as attitude markers.

And then which type of adverbs "also" is?

To discuss conveniently, please take the following quotation as example.

> I'm cold, and I'm also hungry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Also** is a [focusing adverb](http://www.perfectyourenglish.com/grammar/focus-adverbs.htm), as it includes somebody, something or an activity in the group of people, things or activities that you are talking about.

> The whole audience, and also **the speaker**, was disturbed by the noise outside the meeting room. -*including a person*
>
> Can you please pick up the dry cleaning on the way home, and also **a newspaper**. - *including a thing... a newspaper*
>
> John also **studied physics** while he was at school - *including an activity*

Comment: Thank you. I guess "I'm cold" in my example could be *something*. And then the part in you rule, "it includes somebody, something" becomes *"also" includes "I'm cold"*, right?