# "have a think, think about, consider", are these all idiomatic for the beginning of a discussion?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, idiomatic-language

My another post ([It seems that using **even** sounds more idiomatic and natural in lots of situations, is it true?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239477/109190)) starts with

> Consider these 2 sentences

I guess I could also use these beginnings

> think about these 2 sentences
>
> have a think about these 2 sentences

Are these all idiomatic for the beginning of a discussion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb ***to have a think*** [about something], along with *have a **listen, look, feel,...** [to/of something]* are somewhat "quirky" idiomatic usages, where the underlying verb *(**think, listen, look,...**)* is first "nounified", and that noun is then used as the syntactic "object" of the verb ***to have***.

The end result of applying this conversion is a *verb phrase* with essentially the same meaning as the original single-word verb from which it was "derived". But it's basically a "colloquial" usage, which should be avoided in formal contexts (where you should just use the plain verb form).

---

In many situations, ***consider*** would be exactly synonymous with ***think*** for OP's example, ***but*** there's at least one reasonably well-established context where there's a meaningful difference. In, say, a ***textbook***, it's common for writers to introduce "explanatory example(s)" with something like ***Consider*** [these examples]...

...where the intended sense is more along the lines of an "invitation" - ***Let us*** [consider these examples] **together**, rather than an instruction to the reader / audience to ***think about*** [them] **for themselves**. That's to say, if you see the ***consider*** version in a textbook, the examples will probably be followed by further explanatory text (implying that both the writer *and* the reader are exploring the issue "together"). But if you see the ***think*** version, it's very likely the examples are being presented ***as an exercise for the reader***, with no further discussion in the main text (but there might be relevant guidance / "answers" in an appendix at the end of the textbook).